# Problem tracking what javascript is causing jQuery UI error in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I am getting the following error in firebug regarding jQuery UI.  It would be as simple if it was a matter of a process-of-elimination on the JS on the page, but there is allot of JS as well as some on the page and some on the site.master.

**ERROR**

```
(this.uiDialogTitlebarCloseText = c("<span/>"))
  .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-closethick").text(m.closeText).appendTo 
    is not a function
```

Is there a way in Firebug to see what javascript is the initial caller?

Comment: it should show u. u can expand the error, no? (i know u can do it in chrome's console)

Comment: Debugging jQuery is hard when you chain many functions together. You really should separate all of the chained functions so you can test what each one returns.

Comment: This isn't my JS that is chained.  This is jQuery.UI that is chaining it together. This is code out of the jQuery.UI min file.

Answer (score 1):

Well your problem is likely that `m.closeText` is null.  If you pass a null argument to `text()` it will actually return the text of the element, and not set the text to null.

I'm not sure about how to debug it though.

EDIT: The error is thrown because if `text(null)` returns a string, than you'll be saying `string.appentTo` rather than `$().appendTo`.

Comment: Could be, or could be the `c()` function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Wouldn't the error say `(this.uiDialogTitlebarCloseText = c("<span/>")).addClass is not a function` then?  I'm not actually sure.